# Are TeX/LaTeX questions off-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, close-reasons

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/198211/latex-beamer-how-to-get-distinct-page-numbers-when-using-overlays-closed) was closed as off-topic. Yet it fits squarely within the topic of Super User as defined by the FAQ (it's a question about the beamer plug-in for the TeX program, to put it into general terms).

It's true that asking on the [TeX site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) is likely to elicit a better response, but how is a new user who may not even be aware of its existence (ok, not the case in the particular instance I cited above) supposed to guess that? Could we have

- a policy for users to decide whether to flag or close such questions
- a way for new users to know whether TeX questions are allowed/recommended/not-recommended/forbidden at Super User

Comment: Related question, but with wider scope: [Is Super User dying?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1297/is-super-user-dying/1300) - check Gnoupi's [answer](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1297/is-super-user-dying/1301#1301) for the most comprehensive of the lot. Basic summary of my opinion: remember the site is about the **community of users** as much as it is the questions, look at the Unix/Linux SE beta vs AskUbuntu - major overlap in questions, seperate types of users.

Answer (score 3):

I agree... and if every question that is also on topic on an area51/other SE site would automatically be off topic on Superuser, we'd better close the whole damn site.

All Ubuntu/Apple or Android syncing/Unix/Linux questions should then be closed as off topic on Superuser...

A quick count from the Superuser homepage reveals that at least 14 currently featured questions should be closed off topic.

Furthermore, should we even close question as off topic when they are on topic on Superuser but an in beta SE site on the topic is online? Especially since I don't see an in beta SE site as fully operational. (*careful: "worthy"*)

Answer (score 1):

Just a side-note.

Although there are overlap, it is up to the more mature sites to assist and help other SE sites grow and reach potential. This question was closed because it had a better chance of getting answers from a site focussed on Latex. As a norm based on the **level** of the question, if the community believes it will get a better response from a more specific target audience, it will be done. That question was around a few hours before migration, and didn't gain a single answer. It made sense to migrate, and in this case close and manually move the question.

Some questions are rated on individual basis, and sometimes a decision will be made to best assist the user that posted the question. It doesn't mean it is going to become the rule. As with everything, there are edge cases, and this happened to be one of them.